# C# & SQL Server 2012 : Get current user's username

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012

I have built an application in C# and SQL Server. Is it possible to get the username of the logged in user in stored procedure in SQL Server from the application? Without passing it as an argument to the stored procedure? I want the username of the application user not the SQL Server user.

I tried `suser_name()` but it returns the SQL Server user.

I want the username from the table: `dbo.aspnet_Users`

Comment: How is the application authenticating to SQL Server?  That's the "user" as far as SQL Server is concerned.

Comment: have you tried: `CURRENT_USER` or `USER_NAME` ? (documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/current-user-transact-sql)

Comment: Tried it and its the same with suser_name()

Comment: how are you logging into the sql server?

Comment: from ConnectionStrings

Comment: @alxem: Based on your edit... It's *highly unlikely* that SQL Server is using that table for authentication.  Your *application* is using that.  So it's application-specific data.  You'd need to provide that information to SQL Server from the application.  As far as SQL Server is concerned, that's just a table with data like any other.

Comment: @David so the only way is to pass it as a parameter to the stored procedure. right?

Comment: It's not possible. The SQL doesn't know the application user. The user logged in to your application, every connection from application to sql server use normally the same database user. The SQL server only know the database user from connection string.

Answer (score 2):

> I want the username from the table: `dbo.aspnet_Users`

Aye, there's the rub.  As far as SQL Server is concerned, that table has nothing to do with authentication.  That's application data, just like any other application data.  The "user" from *SQL Server's* perspective is whatever authentication is being specified in the connection string that the application is using.

Since this is application data, the application would need to tell SQL Server what to do with this data.  In this case that would mean supplying the stored procedure with the value to use.  Whether that value is a username string, an identifier from that table to use as a foreign key, etc... As far as SQL Server is concerned it's just a value from a data table like any other.

In short, SQL Server has no way to *infer* the value you want to use.  You have to specify it.